# Wordpress - Hide Comments but keep Woocommerce Reviews

Tags: php, wordpress

I usually use the following PHP in my functions.php which completely removes comments from the front end and backend of any Wordpress website:-

```
/**
 * Disable Comments
 */

 // Disable support for comments and trackbacks in post types
function df_disable_comments_post_types_support() {
    $post_types = get_post_types();
    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        if(post_type_supports($post_type, 'comments')) {
            remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'comments');
            remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'trackbacks');
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'df_disable_comments_post_types_support');

// Close comments on the front-end
function df_disable_comments_status() {
    return false;
}
add_filter('comments_open', 'df_disable_comments_status', 20, 2);
add_filter('pings_open', 'df_disable_comments_status', 20, 2);

// Hide existing comments
function df_disable_comments_hide_existing_comments($comments) {
    $comments = array();
    return $comments;
}
add_filter('comments_array', 'df_disable_comments_hide_existing_comments', 10, 2);

// Remove comments page in menu
function df_disable_comments_admin_menu() {
    remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'df_disable_comments_admin_menu');

// Redirect any user trying to access comments page
function df_disable_comments_admin_menu_redirect() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow === 'edit-comments.php') {
        wp_redirect(admin_url()); exit;
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'df_disable_comments_admin_menu_redirect');

// Remove comments metabox from dashboard
function df_disable_comments_dashboard() {
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_recent_comments', 'dashboard', 'normal');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'df_disable_comments_dashboard');

// Remove comments links from admin bar
function df_disable_comments_admin_bar() {
    if (is_admin_bar_showing()) {
        remove_action('admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_comments_menu', 60);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'df_disable_comments_admin_bar');
```

The problem is, this hides/removes product reviews when using the Woocommerce plugin. Is there a way to disable comments completely whilst keeping the Woocommerce reviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried this but I think it should work. change the 1st function like this

```
  // Disable support for comments and trackbacks in post types
function df_disable_comments_post_types_support() {
  $post_types = get_post_types();
foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
    if(post_type_supports($post_type, 'comments')) {
        if (!$post_type=='product'){
        remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'comments');
        remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'trackbacks');
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although this didn't work because of this line was still hiding it `add_filter('comments_open', 'df_disable_comments_status', 20, 2);` so I changed this to:-
`$server_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($server_url, "/product/") != true){
 add_filter('comments_open', 'df_disable_comments_status', 20, 2);
}`
and now it works. @Deepti chipdey